# Angular CLI SCSS module build failed on windows

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, node-sass, angular7

I have created a new angular application with the angular cli (`ng new my-app --style=scss`). Both `ng serve` and `ng build` fail if any scss file has any content (even the initial comment in `styles.scss` fails to compile):

`body {
  display: block;
}`

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   TypeError: Instance of 'dz': type 'dz' is not a subtype of type
>   'n'

My system:

- Angular CLI: 7.0.3
- Node: 8.9.3
- OS: win32 x64
- node-sass: 4.10.0
- sass-loader: 7.1.0
- npm: 6.4.1

It works on another windows machine.

Comment: I could find an article mentioning a similar error, but it's related to dart-sass:
https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling global sass with `npm uninstall -g sass`, the build worked.